# The mergesort code is not giving an output "Segmentation fault" something?

Tags: c++, recursion, mergesort

I went through the code several times but cant spot any mistake or error. The output is not showing in VS code and on online IDE its saying segmentation fault which i cant understand what it means. I apologize if this is due to any silly mistake but I have wasted a lot of time on this . please help.

````
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge_(int a[], int s, int e){
    int mid = (s+e)/2;

    int i = s;
    int j = mid+1;
    int k = s;

    int temp[100];

    while (i<=mid && j<=e)
    {
        if(a[i] < a[j]){
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else{
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
        }
    }
    
    while(i<=mid){
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    
    while(j<=e){
        temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }

    //we need to copy all elements to original arrays
    for (int i = s; i <= e; i++)
    {
        a[i] = temp[i];
    }
    

}

void merge_sort(int a[], int s, int e){
    //base case - 1 or 0 elemnts
    if(s>=e){
        return;
    }

    //follow 3 steps
    //1. Divide
    int mid = (s+e)/2;

    //recursively the arrays - s, mid and mid+1,e
    merge_sort(a,s,mid);
    merge_sort(a,mid-1,e);

    //merge the two parts
    merge_(a,s,e);
}

int main(){

    int a[100];
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    merge_sort(a,0,n-1);

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }

    
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: You might find this documentation on using a debugger useful : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug. You can then single step through your code, examine all its effects and find the cause of your crash

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might come from

```
merge_sort(a,s,mid);
merge_sort(a,mid-1,e);
```

The second call always satisfies s < e, so the recursion does not get aborted, also you include a[mid] and a[mid-1] in both divisions.

I believe the following might work

```
merge_sort(a,s,mid-1);
merge_sort(a,mid,e);
```

If not, please try to get more information on where the recursion fails

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from this line.

`merge_sort(a,mid-1,e)`

It is being called with `mid` being zero.  Then `s` is -1 inside the function.  Accessing the array `a` with an offset of -1 obviously causes a segmentation fault.  Did you mean to put `mid+1` instead?

Also, next time please add...

```
cout << "Enter size of list: "; 
cin >> n;

for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    cout << "Enter integer element " << i << ": ";
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

Or even better, temporarily hardcode the array to avoid asking for keyboard input altogether.

I understand its unfinished, but sharing code that asks for keyboard input without any prompt whatsoever is hella confusing.

Comment: Thanks it worked with `mid+1` and sorry I didn't think about others perspective.

Comment: You're welcome.  Another tip when you're debugging low-level algorithmic code like this is to *always* add checks on the index bounds before you access an array.  Add  `if ( 100 <= s || s < 0 ) { cout << "array index out of bounds"; return; }`.  Only remove the bounds checking ( for optimal speed ) *after* you've thoroughly tested the code with all kinds of input.